# ChromeDriver permissions are set, but not allowing it to run?

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins

I'm using selenium with chrome driver, along with with jenkins to run my tests through. I get this error output when build a test. My permissions for chromedriver are set for 777 by the user 'jenkins' and group 'jenkins'. Any ideas?

```
======================================================================
ERROR: setUpClass (test.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py", line 68, in start
self.service_args, env=env, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 848, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1446, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test2/test.py", line 11, in setUpClass
cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py", line 80, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), docs_msg)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.005s

FAILED (errors=1)
Recording test results
ERROR: Publisher 'Publish JUnit test result report' failed: No test report files were found. Configuration error?
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: What is `chrome_driver_path`'s value? Are you sure it is pointing to the same executable you were giving 777 to?

Comment: It points to the chromedriver within my testing directory. I've read that selenium looks for it within /usr/bin instead. All of which have permission 777 and ownership by the jenkins user.

Comment: It would look it in the `PATH` which usually points to the one located in `/usr/bin/chromedriver`. But, here you are explicitly telling it to use the one located in your testing directory. Check it's permissions.

Comment: I will and update. What's strange is I've ran a    ls -lR on the directory containing my files, and it shows chromedriver as a directory rather than an executable.

Comment: Yeah, that is definitely strange. Btw, just a sanity check. Try running it via `cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome()` letting it use the "system-level" chromedriver.

Comment: That fixed my issue and everything is running smoothly!

Comment: Yeah, I had to copy the chromedriver file in /usr/bin and now it is working. I had it in a test folder before.